# React-router scroll to top when back button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I was able to solve the scroll position problem in react router by creating a method

```
 scrollToTop() {
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

then applying it to a button with

```
onClick={scrollToTop}
```

This works for links but this doesnt work when the back button is clicked. How can I make it also work for the back button?

Comment: Back button means you are rendering other component altogether. Try adding this method in the `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` where you navigate to.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration/scroll-to-top they have this on docs inside life cycle methods

Answer (score 0):

I created a new component to do this function.

ScrollToTop.jsx

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
    import $ from 'jquery'

    class ScrollToTop extends Component {

      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) { 
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow');
         return false;
        }
      }
      render() {
        return (
                 this.props.children

            )
      }
    }

    export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

Add this component on the root of your react app

```
index.js


    import React from 'react'
    import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import App from './jsx/App.jsx'
    import {browserHistory} from 'react-router'
    import {HashRouter as Routers} from 'react-router-dom'
    import ScrollToTop from './jsx/ScrollToTop.jsx'
    import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import {store} from './redux/store'
    ReactDOM.render((
         <Provider store={store}>
           <Routers>
           <ScrollToTop>
                <App />
           </ScrollToTop>
            </Routers>
            </Provider>
        ),document.getElementById('main-container'))
```